# APNS. C++: extract Identifier from error responce

Tags: c++, c, apple-push-notifications

I have a C++ application which sends Apple push notifications

It uses Enhanced Notification Format https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/LegacyFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH105-SW5

Sometimes I receive errors and would like to parse it properly

This is an explanation of error response format:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4

We have 1 byte command, 1 byte status and 4 bytes identifier.
I have a problem with Identifier extraction

This is my code how to extract command and status

```
 char data[6];
 ...
 int Command = data[0];
 int Status = data[1];
 int Identifier = ...;
```

Please help me with identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is to make an integer out of four bytes, it can be done with:

```
char data[6];
...
int Command = data[0];
int Status = data[1];
int Identifier = (data[2] << 24) 
               | (data[3] << 16) 
               | (data[4] << 8) 
               | data[5];
```

This treats the identifier as big-endian, but since the documentation says that the id is opaque, you should be okay, if you treat the id as big endian throughout your application.

The documentation also mentions bytes, not chars, so perhaps your variables should all be unsigned?

Comment: I tryed this and looks like it works int. Identifier = (int)data[2] + ((int)data[3] << 8) + ((int)data[4]<<16) + ((int)data[5]<<24)

.Is it a right way?

Comment: You can substitute bitwise or `|` with addition here, but it is not the same in all cases. (Bitwise or is like addition without carry.) I prefer to have my expressions either all bitwise or all arithmetic. The order in which you shift your bits determines the identifier. The id is opaque, so it doesn't have any meaning to the client code. Choose one representation and stick to it in your code, i.e. use the same byte order when writing it back.

Comment: Got it also in a short way:  int Identifier = *(int *)&data[2];